# how to execute sql query in yii?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I want to execute a query in a view page in Yii, here is my code:

```
$connection=Yii::app()->db;
$connection->active=true;
$sql = "insert into news(idNews, news, display) values('', 'anything', 0)";
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
$command->execute();
```

but nothing is happened, what is the error with my code?

Comment: I don't know YII, but from the first look `createCommand`  returns a normal PDO. So at first you need check if `$command->execute()` `true`, if not you have check what error mysql reports.

Comment: if `idNews` is auto incremental, you don't have to pass anything about it, also check `/runtime/application.log` if an error happend and you missed it

Comment: Using data management requests such as inserts goes against the practice of separating views, business logic and data management, which is used in MVC frameworks such as Yii. If you have to do this, you should re-evaluate your need to use a framework such as Yii.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you execute a query in a view page?In the data access layer is the place you usually do it from. You can try first in the controller.

Here you can read about Data Access Objects in Yii:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao

Answer (score 5):

Or:

```
$sql = 'insert into news (news, display) values (:news, :display)';
$parameters = array(':user_id'=>'', ':created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute($parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$news = new News();
$news->news = "anything";
$news->display = 0;
$news->save(false);
```

Comment: @user3194430 do you have News model?

Comment: I posted one more answer, try that and let me know

Comment: ohh, I forgot to mention that the php file that contian this code is not in the protected dir

Comment: i know, but I putted it outside the protected dir, because thers is an ajax function need to use the file

Comment: I am not sure bro) Why dont you do your ajax functions in controller?

Comment: ok I will to do that, but my ajax function should send data to php and stay at the same page, without refresh the page or redirect to the php page.